# Affine transformation of map with R's sf package produces invalid bounding box values

Tags: r, r-sf, coordinate-systems

When trying to perform an affine transformation on an `sf` object, the projection of the transformed object does not work properly. Specifically, I have an `sf` object called `gdfk` that has a geometry column that represents boundaries of municipalities, and I implement the following code on it:

```
gdfl <- gdfk
crs <- st_geometry(gdfk)
scale <- 0.5; up <- 1000; left <- 1000; rotate <- 0                      # Parameters
M <- {(rotate/180)*pi} %>% {c(cos(.), sin(.), -sin(.), cos(.))} %>% 
  matrix(., nrow = 2, ncol = 2)                                          # Rotation matrix
p <- summarize(select(gdfl, geometry)) %>% {st_centroid(st_geometry(.))} # Point of rotation
geom <- (st_geometry(gdfl) - p) * scale * M + p + c(left, up)            # Transformation
st_crs(gdfl) <- crs                                                      # CRS assignment
```

The code performs the transformation without problems, creating the `gdfl` object. But when I try to plot a map of the geometries of `gdfk` and `gdfl` together using the `tm` package and the code

```
tm_shape(gdfk) + tm_borders() + tm_shape(gdfl) + tm_borders()
```

I get the following error message.

```
Warning messages:
1: In sf::st_is_longlat(shp2) :
  bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
2: In st_is_longlat(x) :
  bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
3: In st_is_longlat(x) :
  bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
4: In st_is_longlat(x) :
  bounding box has potentially an invalid value range for longlat data
```

As a result, I only get the plot of the untransformed geometry, but not of the transformed one. (Using the `plot` function, I am able to plot each geometry separately though.) What should I do to able to make an affine transformation on an `sf` object work properly?

Comment: What are the up and left parameters supposed to accomplish? The values seem kind of incongruous in context of a longlat CRS (there are only 360 degrees to go around...)

Comment: Hi, @JindraLacko. They are supposed to move the map leftwards and upwards, respectively. It is a shift as here: https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/geometric-operations.html#affine-transformations.

Comment: Then try shifting the map by a smaller amount - say 5 units, and iterate from there. You seem to be using a longlat CRS (such as WGS84 / EPSG 4326) and in such a context you are not supposed to get off the geosphere. This gives a hard limit on your bbox. e.g. you can't go more north than 90°N; 1000° N don't make any  sense.

Comment: Hi, @JindraLacko. Your suggestion worked just fine. I thought I had to treat the shift in meters, but it seems that I have to treat it in terms of degrees instead; therefore, I should use small numbers, as you suggested. Thanks (again) for the help.

Comment: glad to be of service! The shift units are always in units of your CRS - meters in metric systems, degrees in geographic ones and even US survey feet in the cruel and unusual coordinate systems the Americans sometimes use ...